# Filter out segments of decreasing values (with extra conditions)

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, filtering

I am writing a script to identify the decreasing segments of a river discharge dataset with :

- x-axis : time (date)
- y-axis : flow

[Data looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IIPD.png)

I would like to filter out automatically the decreasing segments with specific conditions. A segment is defined as follows :

- the segment initial value is minimum 12
- the segment ending part should reach at least 7.5 but it can go lower
- it contains mainly decreasing values BUT minor increasing parts are tolerated
- tolerated increasing parts have a y-shift lower than 5% of the current segment initial flow value (i.e. for an initial flow of 15, increasing peaks lower than 0.75 are tolerated)
- the segment ends before the next big increase

Taking into account these conditions, [this is the only segment I want to keep (red part).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzpFz.png)

I'm confused on what to do, I'm lacking of R knowledge and afraid to miss an obvious solution. I already got the "peak" indexes (for flow>12) with the following code :

```
## get a column with "1" for decreasing values and "0" for increasing values

df <- df %>% mutate(sign = NA)

sapply(1:nrow(df)-1, function(i){
  df$sign[i] <<- df$flow[i] - df$flow[i+1]
})

df <- df %>% mutate(sign=case_when(sign>=0 ~ 1, sign<0 ~ 0))

## get the indexes of the beginning of each decreasing segment

rle <- rle(df$sign)
rle$lengths <- cumsum(rle$lengths)
rle <- rle$lengths[which(rle$values==0)]
rle <- rle + 1

## only keep the indexes with flow > 12

rle <- rle[rle %in% which(df$flow>12)]
```

And now I have no clue how to properly make a script that can apply the two other conditions, mainly because of the tolerance for the little increasing parts (the 5% condition).

Here is a reproducible example :

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16594, 16595, 16596, 16597, 
                                        16598, 16599, 16600, 16601, 16602, 16603, 16604, 16605, 16606, 
                                        16607, 16608, 16609, 16610, 16611, 16612, 16613, 16614, 16615, 
                                        16616, 16617, 16618, 16619, 16620, 16621, 16622, 16623, 16624, 
                                        16625, 16626, 16627, 16628, 16629, 16630, 16631, 16632, 16633, 
                                        16634, 16635, 16636, 16637, 16638, 16639, 16640, 16641, 16642, 
                                        16643, 16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 16648, 16649, 16650, 16651, 
                                        16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 16657, 16658, 16659, 16660, 
                                        16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 16666, 16667, 16668, 16669, 
                                        16670, 16671, 16672, 16673, 16674, 16675, 16676, 16677, 16678, 
                                        16679, 16680, 16681, 16682, 16683, 16684, 16685, 16686, 16687, 
                                        16688, 16689, 16690, 16691, 16692, 16693, 16694, 16695, 16696, 
                                        16697, 16698, 16699, 16700, 16701, 16702, 16703, 16704, 16705, 
                                        16706, 16707, 16708, 16709, 16710, 16711, 16712, 16713, 16714, 
                                        16715, 16716, 16717, 16718, 16719, 16720, 16721, 16722, 16723, 
                                        16724, 16725, 16726, 16727, 16728, 16729, 16730, 16731, 16732, 
                                        16733, 16734, 16735, 16736, 16737, 16738, 16739, 16740, 16741, 
                                        16742, 16743, 16744, 16745, 16746, 16747, 16748, 16749, 16750, 
                                        16751, 16752, 16753, 16754, 16755, 16756, 16757, 16758, 16759, 
                                        16760, 16761, 16762, 16763, 16764, 16765, 16766, 16767, 16768, 
                                        16769, 16770, 16771, 16772, 16773, 16774, 16775, 16776, 16777, 
                                        16778, 16779, 16780, 16781, 16782, 16783, 16784, 16785, 16786, 
                                        16787, 16788, 16789, 16790, 16791, 16792, 16793, 16794, 16795, 
                                        16796, 16797, 16798, 16799, 16800, 16801, 16802, 16803, 16804, 
                                        16805, 16806, 16807, 16808, 16809, 16810, 16811, 16812, 16813, 
                                        16814, 16815, 16816, 16817, 16818, 16819, 16820), class = "Date"), 
                     flow = c(10.3, 10.3833333333333, 10.5666666666667, 10.6625, 
                              10.7416666666667, 12.0166666666667, 12.9375, 14.2166666666667, 
                              15.0666666666667, 15.7833333333333, 16.125, 15.95, 15.6041666666667, 
                              15.1375, 14.55, 14.1, 13.7708333333333, 13.4125, 13.05, 12.7875, 
                              12.525, 12.2625, 12.0791666666667, 11.8666666666667, 11.6291666666667, 
                              11.4166666666667, 11.1916666666667, 11.0708333333333, 10.8875, 
                              10.7458333333333, 10.6416666666667, 10.5666666666667, 10.4333333333333, 
                              10.3125, 10.2, 10.1416666666667, 10.025, 9.95125, 9.8775, 
                              9.77666666666667, 9.73833333333333, 9.68, 9.60958333333333, 
                              9.51791666666667, 9.455, 9.43083333333333, 9.39166666666667, 
                              9.2775, 9.2275, 9.18458333333333, 9.1225, 9.08291666666667, 
                              9.05083333333333, 9.01083333333333, 8.96625, 8.88208333333333, 
                              8.80875, 8.75416666666667, 8.69583333333333, 8.66416666666667, 
                              8.595, 8.51333333333333, 8.50625, 8.50958333333333, 8.55375, 
                              8.3575, 8.19916666666667, 8.16125, 8.10666666666667, 8.07208333333333, 
                              8.005, 7.955, 7.895, 7.79833333333333, 7.76166666666667, 
                              7.715, 7.73625, 8.1675, 9.86291666666667, 9.8675, 9.45166666666667, 
                              9.0075, 8.63583333333333, 8.33791666666667, 8.11083333333333, 
                              8.02791666666667, 8.03041666666667, 7.98625, 7.9275, 7.84083333333333, 
                              7.71208333333333, 7.64875, 7.63958333333333, 7.58416666666667, 
                              7.52083333333333, 7.50125, 7.44875, 7.44916666666667, 7.5775, 
                              7.95, 7.86, 7.7575, 8.32208333333333, 8.24833333333333, 8.01958333333333, 
                              7.85791666666667, 7.70166666666667, 7.50291666666667, 7.35, 
                              7.23958333333333, 7.08416666666667, 6.9825, 6.92375, 7.03, 
                              7.30291666666667, 7.205, 6.97375, 8.83583333333333, 18.1041666666667, 
                              20.5208333333333, 19.7041666666667, 18.3166666666667, 17.1, 
                              15.9875, 15.2458333333333, 14.4625, 13.8, 15.2166666666667, 
                              17.9916666666667, 18.1708333333333, 17.5166666666667, 16.6083333333333, 
                              15.9416666666667, 15.45, 15.0958333333333, 14.7666666666667, 
                              14.4958333333333, 14.1, 13.7375, 13.35, 13.025, 12.8916666666667, 
                              12.6083333333333, 13.6708333333333, 14.5833333333333, 14.4666666666667, 
                              14.025, 13.6458333333333, 13.3166666666667, 13.1625, 13.5083333333333, 
                              13.9, 13.975, 13.6958333333333, 13.4458333333333, 13.1458333333333, 
                              12.7416666666667, 12.4, 12.1416666666667, 11.9416666666667, 
                              11.6833333333333, 11.4083333333333, 11.1833333333333, 11.025, 
                              10.6583333333333, 10.5166666666667, 10.4416666666667, 10.3833333333333, 
                              10.25, 10.0875, 9.9325, 9.89, 9.87083333333333, 9.65416666666667, 
                              9.40166666666667, 9.25791666666667, 9.11791666666667, 8.955, 
                              8.83458333333333, 8.75, 8.66541666666667, 8.59125, 8.74083333333333, 
                              9.00041666666667, 8.92625, 8.69541666666667, 8.615, 8.91416666666667, 
                              8.51583333333333, 8.50041666666667, 8.39541666666667, 8.2425, 
                              8.11208333333333, 8.04708333333333, 7.96916666666667, 7.91583333333333, 
                              7.8475, 7.83875, 7.77708333333333, 7.71083333333333, 7.60875, 
                              7.48375, 7.35625, 7.25583333333333, 7.23583333333333, 7.12166666666667, 
                              7.11375, 7.07, 7.23375, 8.99166666666667, 10.2475, 10.4333333333333, 
                              10.2625, 10.1, 9.98083333333333, 10.15, 10.825, 11.7416666666667, 
                              11.9333333333333, 11.9083333333333, 11.8666666666667, 11.6833333333333, 
                              11.5875, 11.3583333333333, 11.075, 10.8208333333333, 10.6708333333333
                     )), row.names = c(NA, -227L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
                       date = structure(list(format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"), class = c("collector_datetime", 
                                                                                   "collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                     "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. First post here, so I would take any advice to improve my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a `sign` column can be simplified by using `lead()`. In that case it would be `df = df %>% mutate(sign = case_when(flow - lead(flow) >= 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))`

Comment: To my mind, the way you describe the conditions for filtering the dataframe could be more precise. Can you make the description clearer? Also, in the posted image of what you want to keep, is the red part the one you want to keep or the one you want to get rid of?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I edited the description and tried to be more precise with the segment conditions. About the red part, it is the part I want to keep. Thanks

Comment: Based on the data and your specifications, I am unsure how you are expecting to keep only the part in red. For example: group starting from row 11 would also have an initial value greater than 12, and lowest value being 7.7 and the segment you want to keep has a lowest value of 7.1 and would not meet the conditions.

Comment: sorry, it might be confusing for the lowest value. I want the segment to reach at least 7.5 or even less. This is why the segment you described (from row 11) doesn't meet the conditions, by not reaching at least a flow of 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `datatable`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df = df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  # flow*0.05 will add the 5% tolerance
  mutate(sign = case_when((flow-lead(flow))+(flow*0.05) >= 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  # group by run-length type id
  group_by(rleid(sign), sign) %>%
  filter(first(sign) == 1 & first(flow) >= 12 & min(flow) <= 7.5)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, it works perfectly. I couldn't think of something that concise ! Definitely helped me to understand some R mechanics.